# Structure Preserving Continuous Hash Function

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, hashing, encryption

*This question was originally posted on [super user](https://superuser.com/), but redirected here based on some suggestions.*

I am completely new with computer science, and not only recently did I run into the notion of hashing. Currently, I use `md5sum` for indexing reason, but am curious if hash functions can do more things. After educating myself on the surface by reading the wikipedia page on [hash functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function), I wondered if continuous hash functions can be made true. Luckily, it is called [locality sensitive hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing), and I can find open algorithms online.

What makes me more curious, and is something that I have not found, is can I further ask the continuous hash functions to preserve structure? More specifically, the problem I have in mind is to index all of the files I have. Not only do I hope the indexing to be continuous (so the hash won't change too much while I minor-edit a file), I also want it to preserve structure (so for example if I concatenate two files, the hash of the third file should be a reasonable function in the hash of the first two).

Please let me know if I should provide more specific information. Again, I am completely new to this field, so I might have missed something obvious.

Comment: That is not a good idea. That hash function will be weak about finding collisions.

Comment: I don't see why that's the case. .. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: Since you tagged encryption, in short, due to the avalanche criteria, from Cryptographic Hash functions we want; changing one bit in the input, should change half of the output bit, randomly. If not, your hash function will have non-generic collisions.